# c++ - error: member access into incomplete type in base class virtual function

Tags: c++

I have a base class `Shape` and it has a virtual function `intersect()`.

The `HitRecord` is a struct defined in the same `.h` file.

Also, `Shape` has a child class `Triangle`. I'm trying to access a member of `HitRecord` in `Shape::intersect()` but I got an error `error: member access into incomplete type in base class virtual function`

It is strange that I could do this in the child class but can't in the base class.

Does it because of it's a **virtual** function?

**Note:** Another strange thing: I can run on my Ubuntu 16.04 but encounter this error on my mac.

**code**

```
struct HitRecord;   // forward declaration

class Shape {
public:
    virtual bool intersect(Ray& r, HitRecord& rec) {
        std::cout << "Child intersect() is not implement." << std::endl;
        rec.obj = this;
        return false;
    }
}

struct HitRecord {
    float t;
    vec3f p;    // point coord
    vec3f norm;
    Shape* obj;
};

class Triangle: public Shape {
public:
    Mesh* mesh_ptr;
    unsigned int vertexIndex[3];

    Triangle() {...}

    Triangle(Mesh* m) {...}

    inline bool intersect(Ray& r, HitRecord& rec);
}

inline bool Triangle::intersect(Ray& r, HitRecord& rec) {
    vec3f n = cross(v1-v0, v2-v0);
    float t = - (dot(n, r.origin())+d) / dot(n, r.direction());
    vec3f p = r.origin() + t*r.direction();

    rec.t = t;
    rec.p = p;
    rec.norm = unit(n);
    rec.obj = this;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is known as circular dependency.

In your code..

```
// in shape.h

struct HitRecord;   // forward declaration

                    // this forward declaration means all you can do until 
                    // the struct is fully declared is declare a pointer
                    // or a reference to it.  No more.

class Shape {
public:
    virtual bool intersect(Ray& r, HitRecord& rec);  // <-- this is fine


    virtual bool intersect(Ray& r, HitRecord& rec) {
        //...
        rec.obj = this;   // <-- this is where you hit an error. the compiler
                          // doesn't know yet what HitRecord::obj is.
        return false;
    }
};


.. in hitrecord.h...

struct HitRecord {
    float t;
    vec3f p;    // point coord
    vec3f norm;
    Shape* obj;
};


 // this would usually reside in shape.cpp, but what's important is the order
 // in which the compiler reads the successive declarations

 #include "shape.h"
 #include "hitrecord.h"   // for example...

 bool Shape::intersect(Ray& r, HitRecord& rec) 
 {
 //...
     rec.obj = this;   // Now, the compiler knwos all about HitRecord
                       // so this will compile.
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the function being marked `virtual`. How can the compiler know what `rec.obj` is (if such member exists) without knowing the definition of `rec`'s type?

Define `Shape::intersect` out-of-line after the definition of `HitRecord` (don't put everything in one file, ideally) or swap the order of `Shape`/`HitRecord` definitions and forward-declare `Shape`.

Comment: Why forward declaration of `HitRecord` can't handle this situation? The signature of `intersect()` also contain `HitRecord` but the compiler does not throw an error?

Comment: You can declare a pointer or a reference of an incomplete type.